# Parse each row of Pandas df to extract list of actors from each URL

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am newly learning how to do web scraping in Python and could use some help. I want to parse each url in the below table and extract a list of the cast members in each movie.

| Date | Name | Year | Letterboxd URI | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-04-06 | Knives Out | 2019 | https://boxd.it/jWEA | 4.0 |
| 2020-04-07 | Pulp Fiction | 1994 | https://boxd.it/29Pq | 5.0 |

Ultimate goal is to have a new df that shows each cast member that gets extracted, matching them to the movie and rating as well.

| Actor | Movie | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel Craig | Knives Out | 4.0 |
| Bruce Willis | Pulp Fiction | 5.0 |

Comment: Well, that requires the whole parsing script to be done. You may try doing it yourself with the help of [documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and guides and come back here with a specific question if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# replicate given data
columns = ['Date', 'Name', 'Year', 'Letterboxd URI', 'Rating']
r1 = ['2020-04-06', 'Knives Out', '2019', 'https://boxd.it/jWEA', '4.0']
r2 = ['2020-04-07', 'Pulp Fiction', '1994', 'https://boxd.it/29Pq', '5.0']
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([r1], columns=columns)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([r2], columns=columns)
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])


columns = ['Movie', 'Actor', 'Rating']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    # request content and fetching a-tag inside cast_list div
    r = requests.get(row['Letterboxd URI'])
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    # as each cast encapsulate inside <a> and <div cast-list...>
    cast_soup = soup.select_one('[class="cast-list text-sluglist"]')
    cast_list = [a.get_text().strip() for a in cast_soup.find_all("a")]
    
    # putting data into new_df
    movie, rating = row['Name'], row['Rating'] # old value from tables
    for cast in cast_list:
        df_ = pd.DataFrame([[movie, cast, rating]], columns=columns)
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df_])
        
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
new_df
```

```
|    | Movie        | Actor                   |   Rating |
|---:|:-------------|:------------------------|---------:|
|  0 | Knives Out   | Daniel Craig            |        4 |
|  1 | Knives Out   | Chris Evans             |        4 |
|  2 | Knives Out   | Ana de Armas            |        4 |
|  3 | Knives Out   | Jamie Lee Curtis        |        4 |
| 33 | Pulp Fiction | John Travolta           |        5 |
| 34 | Pulp Fiction | Samuel L. Jackson       |        5 |
| 35 | Pulp Fiction | Uma Thurman             |        5 |
```

Comment: You are saint, thank you so much! If you have time to help me with one last part that would be amazing - I am finding that when I use the full csv as df, instead of just the sample data I provided you, that I get an error saying 'NoneType' object is not callable. It appears in this line: `cast_soup = soup.select_one('[class="cast-list text-sluglist"]')`... any idea how I can fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: From my opinion, it might be blocked or invalid `requests` that soup could not crawling data. Try debugging from `r = requests.get($url)` and `soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')` to see whether the response is 200 and there is data in your soup, if both are ok, please inspecting your df next.